# Difference in PIP format

Tags: python, pip

What is the difference between:

```
python -m pip install forecasting
```

and

```
pip install forecasting
```

In my environment, the first is working when the second format raise the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'

Comment: It seems like pip is installed incorrectly, are you on linux, can you reinstall `pip` please ?

Comment: seems to be [related](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5373)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to your first question.**

From [pip docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/)
pip is a command line program. When you install pip, a pip command is added to your system, which can be run from the command prompt as follows:

```
$ pip <pip arguments>
```

If you cannot run the pip command directly (possibly because the location where it was installed isn't on your operating system's PATH) then you can run pip via the Python interpreter:

```
$ python -m pip <pip arguments>
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. If `pip` is not in your PATH, you would get an error saying **Command not found** and not **ModuleNotFoundError**. So this is directly related with pip having been installed incorrectly or it breaking down.

Comment: There is part of the answer which is correct. He asked about the difference between two types of commands too.

Comment: I removed the part where I stated this may be the reason behind error.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to this GitHub issue:

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5373

Try the following command:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Answer (score 1):

They're two different ways a package can expose commands to the commandline.

`pip` is a [`console_script` entry-point](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point). Any package can define globally available commands that way, and PIP (the package) uses it to define `pip` (the command).

In case of `pip`, the function they're executing using this method is set to [`pip._internal.main()`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/setup.py#L75):

```
entry_points={
    "console_scripts": [
        "pip=pip._internal:main",
    ],
},
```

On the other side `python -m pip` is using a [switch for calling modules](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m). If your module contains a `__main__.py` file, this file will simply be interpreted and executed by the Python interpreter.

In case of `python -m pip`, [this file essentially contains](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/__main__.py)

```
from pip._internal import main as _main 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(_main())
```

so the two commands try to do the same.

However, recently PIP has shown some weird quirks [[1]](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240) [[2]](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5373) that cause one of the two to work, and the other one to fail.